# json stringify mvc slashes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, stringify

I am developing an app wtih MVC 5. There are plenty of places where I am returning json results from controller to view. For example:

```
return Json(new { StdInCSList = lsic, CSStatusList = CSStatusList }, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Yet every single time, when I try to use javascript to stringify the returned json objects, it addes slashes to it. If I use JSON.parse on the object, it will raise the "invalid character" error.

This is truely frustrating. JSON.parse is a rather standard function. One would think that asp.net's Json function would be able to return something that is compatible to it. Yet, it simply is not.

I would really appreciate help on how to stringify (or parse) a Json object that is returned to the view from the MVC controller. Many thanks!

Comment: Show an example of "broken" JSON. "Yet, it simply is not." -- that's a brave statement.

Comment: You don't. Its just `return Json(new { StdInCSList = lsic, CSStatusList = CSStatusList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and in you success call back - `success: function(data) {`, access the properties, e.g. `data.StdInCSList` and `data.CSStatusList`

Comment: Why do you want to stringify the returned JSON objects?